# Is there any way to call remote api endpoints based on firebase analytics events?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to figure out a way to call an SMS TEXT MESSAGE provider's API endpoint based on events raised from the frontend of my app. Is there any way I can send text messages to my users based on the events being raised from firebase?

Similarly, I would like to explore ways to send Emails using SendGrid's API to my users based on events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [trigger Cloud Functions based on Analytics **conversion** events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events). From the Cloud Functions code, you can do pretty much whatever you want.